# How to calculate the correlation between two images in EMGU?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have two images (let's assume they have the same size), i want to calculate the correlation between the two images Using EMGU and C#.

I didn't found any function that does it and implemented the correlation calculation by myself.. but i'd rather use built in function.

Is such function exist ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe if you will write what is your main goal it would be easier to recommend the right method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Image<>.MatchTemplate()](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/e825d2a7-91fa-75eb-0eb4-3245d70227ee.htm) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Pay attention that if both images are in the same size  (as you assumed) - you should crop the "pattern" to some smaller size (DON'T SCALE..) in order to actually generate some correlation. I'd offer to enter into image in x&y to get localization in all directions (+- xy)